# Snowflake stored procedure timezone without manipulation

Tags: javascript, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am querying a table and storing the date and then need to insert that date as a timestamp to another table.

Currently, I'm using `querieddate.toISOString()` but that manipulates the date and sets 5 hours ahead.

How can I avoid that?

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just use [TO_TIMESTAMP_NTZ](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/to_timestamp.html) on the DATE?

```
SELECT to_date('2022-03-22') as date_a
    ,SYSTEM$TYPEOF(date_a) as date_a_type
    ,to_timestamp_ntz(date_a) as timestamp_a
    ,SYSTEM$TYPEOF(timestamp_a) as timestamp_a_type;
```

| DATE_A | DATE_A_TYPE | TIMESTAMP_A | TIMESTAMP_A_TYPE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-03-22 | DATE[SB4] | 2022-03-22 00:00:00.000 | TIMESTAMP_NTZ(9)[SB16] |

So yes, within the JavaScript, you are being exposed to the fact the default timezone in Snowflake is not UTC, which I think is somewhat poor. But there you have it:

```
CREATE TABLE date_table(date date);
INSERT INTO date_table values (to_date('2022-03-22'));

CREATE TABLE timestamp_table(ts timestamp);

create or replace procedure stproc1()
  returns string not null
  language javascript
  as
  -- "$$" is the delimiter for the beginning and end of the stored procedure.
  $$
    var sql_command = "SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP(date) FROM date_table limit 1;";
    var stmt = snowflake.createStatement( {sqlText: sql_command} );
    var resultSet = stmt.execute();
    resultSet.next();
    var my_sfDate = resultSet.getColumnValue(1);
    
    return my_sfDate.toISOString();
  $$
  ;

call stproc1();
```

| STPROC1 |
| --- |
| 2022-03-22T07:00:00.000Z |

BUT if we also fetch from the date_table the date as epoch seconds as a string (groan).. we can poke that into a timestamp, and avoid Javascripts inability to hold large numbers.

```
create or replace procedure stproc1()
  returns string not null
  language javascript
  as
  -- "$$" is the delimiter for the beginning and end of the stored procedure.
  $$
    var sql_command = "SELECT date, extract('epoch_seconds', date)::text as epoch_secs FROM date_table limit 1;";
    var stmt = snowflake.createStatement( {sqlText: sql_command} );
    var resultSet = stmt.execute();
    resultSet.next();
    var my_sfDate = resultSet.getColumnValue(1);
    var my_epochSec = resultSet.getColumnValue(2);
    
    //return my_epochSec;
     
    sql_command2 = "INSERT INTO timestamp_table values(:1)";
    stmt2 = snowflake.createStatement( {sqlText: sql_command2, binds:[my_epochSec]} );
    var resultSet = stmt2.execute();
    return 0;
  $$
  ;
```

```
call stproc1();
```

```
select * from timestamp_table;
```

| TS |
| --- |
| 2022-03-22 00:00:00.000 |

Comment: it doesn't work inside of the SP

Comment: Agreed, JS seems to not be the thing to handle dates nicely in.

Answer (score 0):

You can instead keep the date as a SQL session variable like this

```
snowflake.execute({sqlText:`set start_date = current_timestamp();`);

snowflake.execute({sqlText:`select * from table where date > $start_date`);
```